# How can I capture a value that comes through POST to execute a procedure stored in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working with Spring Boot, in which I am relatively new, and in this case I am doing a database validation through a Stored Procedue, which I could already solve, the reality is that until now I had done the tests sent the parameter of entry (a mobile number) by GET, but it is required for project reasons, send the parameter through POST, that is to say in a Body with the method:

Method Get

[image]

With a Body using the POST Method:

Request

```
{
  "movil":"04242374781";
}
```

Reponse:

```
{
    "result": "Cliente no encontrado",
    "code": "NA22003"
}
```

mobile is an attribute of the database where the Stored Procedure is executed, for this case it is only necessary to pass that parameter to execute the SP, which returns a response that is not the same object of the database in which it is mobile, then you will see it in the code.

I understand that you can send the parameter for consultation with POST, but in my case try to guide me according to what I got on the internet, but I got an error:

**Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain' not supported]**

[image]

My Code

Main class

```
package com.app.validacion;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

My controller

```
package com.app.validacion.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.app.validacion.dao.DriverBonificadosRepository;
import com.app.validacion.entity.RespuestaVo;


@RestController
public class DriverBonificadosController {

    @Autowired   // Inyeccion de Dependecia, en este caso del Respository
    private DriverBonificadosRepository dao;


    @GetMapping("/service/{movil}")
    public RespuestaVo  ConsultarMovil(@PathVariable("movil") String movil) {
        System.out.println(movil);
        return dao.validarClienteBonifiado(movil);

    }

    /* 
       the code I was trying to use to send a request in JSON and try to get the mobile parameter,but 
       I got an error:
       Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 
        'text/plain' not supported]
    /*
     * @PostMapping(value = "/service",consumes = "application/json", produces="application/json") 
     * public RespuestaVo ValidateClient(@RequestBody DriverBonificados driver) {
     * System.out.println(driver.getMovil()); 
     *   return dao.validarClienteBonifiado(driver.getMovil()); 
      } */


    }
```

My Repository

```
package com.app.validacion.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.app.validacion.entity.DriverBonificados;
import com.app.validacion.entity.RespuestaVo;


@Repository
public interface DriverBonificadosRepository extends JpaRepository<DriverBonificados, Integer> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "call ValidacionClienteBonificado(:movil)")
    RespuestaVo validarClienteBonifiado(@Param("movil") String pMovil);

    }
```

My Entity

```
package com.app.validacion.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="DriveBonificados")
public class DriverBonificados {

    @Id
    private int id;     
    private String movil;
    private String contador;
    private Date fecha_driver;
    private Date fecha_alta;
    private Date fecha_fin;
    private Date codigo_transaccion;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMovil() {
        return movil;
    }
    public void setMovil(String movil) {
        this.movil = movil;
    }
    public String getContador() {
        return contador;
    }
    public void setContador(String contador) {
        this.contador = contador;
    }
    public Date getFecha_driver() {
        return fecha_driver;
    }
    public void setFecha_driver(Date fecha_driver) {
        this.fecha_driver = fecha_driver;
    }
    public Date getFecha_alta() {
        return fecha_alta;
    }
    public void setFecha_alta(Date fecha_alta) {
        this.fecha_alta = fecha_alta;
    }
    public Date getFecha_fin() {
        return fecha_fin;
    }
    public void setFecha_fin(Date fecha_fin) {
        this.fecha_fin = fecha_fin;
    }
    public Date getCodigo_transaccion() {
        return codigo_transaccion;
    }
    public void setCodigo_transaccion(Date codigo_transaccion) {
        this.codigo_transaccion = codigo_transaccion;
    }

}
```

My Model Response

```
package com.app.validacion.entity;


public interface RespuestaVo {

    String getCode();
    String getResult();

}
```

Comment: in your postman-request: set a (request) header: `Content-Type: application/json`..

Comment: (...or switch the according dropdown-item "raw>Text";) ...sorry, nice post for that short answer :)

Comment: If you want to place it as an answer and I will validate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice post, but the (first encountered problem) solution is trivial:

With:

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain' not supported]

and with this postman request, You need to:

- postman specific: switch the (request>body) content type from "Text" to "JSON (application/json)"
- generally: add a (http) header to Your request like

  ```
  Content-Type: application/json;...
  ```

Comment: no big thing, very welcome & glad to help :)  ...of course you have various and flexible options on the server side (e.g. serve different/multiple content types/with/-out/above [tag:spring-data-rest]) ..when you advance. but as "quickstarter" and with the defaults (*spring rest demands content-type=json*), this "postman setting/header" is good to know.